# Visual Studio how to mark warnings with <Obsolete>

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have 400+ warnings and I need to add  to the code where needed.

At this time, I am going to each line then right clicking then selecting "Add Obsolete"

Obviously this is a very slow process. Is there a faster way to do this?

I am using Visual Studio 2019

---

```
<Obsolete>
Dim Conn As New OracleClient.OracleConnection
```

Comment: You should be able to multi-select in the VS IDE window that shows the warnings? I know you can with Code Analysis to Suppress warnings.

Comment: I dont want to "surpress it". I want to add <Obsolete> in front of each warning.

Comment: Why is this tagged vb6 ??

Comment: @EddiGordo it isn't any longer

Comment: What are some examples of the warnings you're getting?